# Is it possible to lock an SD card so it only operates on a certain device?

Tags: encryption, raspberry-pi

I am looking to provide some properiatary software with the raspberry pi as the platform (but this could be with any embedded board). I'm looking for a way for the file system to only be visible on that device.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

You could encrypt the whole disk or the volume using LUKS or dm-crypt if your distribution supports it. It's also possible to encrypt files or directories on the disk while leaving the file-system mountable (but scrambled).  If you go the latter route, it would be a good coding experience to write your own software that encrypts files and then de-crypts them when a key is entered.

Either way, you'll run into an issue: Before using the clear data, someone has to input the key. If the key is stored on the card, nothing prevents an attacker reading the key from a stolen card. If it's input by a person, that person needs to manually enter the key after every boot.